# Ember.js insert content into a named block

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to insert content into a named block with Ember.js/Handlebars?

Rails offers a content_for method, which does exactly what I'm looking for: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method

The application handlebars template looks like this:

```
{{#if isSignedIn}}
  <header>
    [ ... ]
    The content inside the header is different from page to page.
    The client wants buttons inside the header, that each have different actions.
  </header>
{{/if}}
<section id="outer-content-container">
  {{outlet}}
</section>
```

What's the best way to accomplish this with Ember.js/Handlebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

named outlets makes the most sense to me.

Lets say in the application template you have an additional outlet

```
{{outlet dynostuff}}

{{outlet}}
```

And then in each route you want to display different information

```
App.PostRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render(); // render the default stuff

    this.render('favoritePost', {   // the template to render
      into: 'application',                // the template to render into
      outlet: 'dynostuff',              // the name of the outlet in that template
      controller: 'blogPost'        // the controller to use for the template
    });
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/